# How to get IP for stm32?

Tags: c, stm32, ethernet, arp

I want to get IP adress for my STM32.So I am using ARP ethernet protocole frame.

X-> refer to my MAC
Y->Refer to IP address

I connected ethernet cable between the stm32 and computer so, mac address are same for both of them. I choose empty IP addres for STM32 (yy.yy.yy.3 example) 
And than I use "ping yy.yy.yy.3" command line at the terminal so start the ARP requests. And I want to answer this request but any answer couldnt see on wireshark. Where is my mistake ?

Send answer with this line

```
   while (1)
            {
                enc28_packetSend(ARP_req, 42);
            }
```

This is ARP ethernet  packet:

```
unsigned char ARP_req[42] = {
    0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, /* ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dst mac */
    0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, /* src mac */
    0x08, 0x06,                         /* ETH_P_ARP */
    0x00, 0x01,                         /*  ANSWER  */
    0x08, 0x00,                         /* ETH_P_IP */
    0x06,                               /* ETH_ALEN */
    0x04,                               /* 4 */
    0x00, 0x02,                         /* ARPOP_REQUEST */
    0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx /* ar_sha */
    0xyy, 0xyy, 0xyy, 0x03,             /* i
    0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, 0xxx, /* ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff ar_tha */
    0x0a, 0x2a, 0x00, 0x01              /* */
};
```

And this is send function for enc28j60

```
void enc28_packetSend(unsigned char *packet, unsigned int len)
{


    uint8_t retry = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        enc28_writeOp(ENC28J60_BIT_FIELD_SET, ECON1, ECON1_TXRST);
        enc28_writeOp(ENC28J60_BIT_FIELD_CLR, ECON1, ECON1_TXRST);
        enc28_writeOp(ENC28J60_BIT_FIELD_CLR, EIR, EIR_TXERIF | EIR_TXIF);
        if (retry == 0)
        {
            enc28_write(EWRPTL, TXSTART_INIT & 0xFF);
            enc28_write(EWRPTH, TXSTART_INIT >> 8);

            enc28_write(ETXNDL, (TXSTART_INIT + len) & 0xFF);
            enc28_write(ETXNDH, (TXSTART_INIT + len) >> 8);

            enc28_writeOp(ENC28J60_WRITE_BUF_MEM, 0, 0x00);

            enc28_writeBuf(packet, len);
        }
        enc28_writeOp(ENC28J60_BIT_FIELD_SET, ECON1, ECON1_TXRTS);
        uint16_t count = 0;
        while ((enc28_read(EIR) & (EIR_TXIF | EIR_TXERIF)) == 0 && ++count < 1000U)
            //  GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_9);

            ;
        if (!(enc28_read(EIR) & EIR_TXERIF) && count < 1000U)
        {

            //no error start new trasnmission
            // GPIO_SetBits(GPIOE, GPIO_Pin_9);
            break;
        }
        enc28_writeOp(ENC28J60_BIT_FIELD_CLR, ECON1, ECON1_TXRTS);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The ethernet protocol type ETH_P_ARP follows the hardware address type, which is 0x0001 (ethernet), not 0x0002.

Comment: I wrote here 0x02 but i am using 0x01 but again can not success

Comment: ARP gives you MAC from IP, not IP from MAC.  Unless the target has the target IP, it should not answer.

Comment: how can I get the IP for Stm32 with enc28j60 ?

Comment: @stark But the MAC address has already known because two devices connected same ethernet line. Is that true ? Stm32 and my computer connect with ethernet cable, so Have they same address ?

Comment: Two devices with the same MAC canot communicate.  How would you know which device you are addressing?

Comment: @stark How can I find IP addres for my stm32 ? If my computer connect with wi fi and I send to my computer arp protocole is that a true way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your embedded client IP Address that is given by host, you should check DHCP.